# What is the and why is there a difference between request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] and request.content_type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, content-type, httprequest, actiondispatch

I'm seeing two different values for `request.env['CONTENT_TYPE']` and `request.content_type`.

From a separate application, I am sending a request to my Rails application and have explicitly set the `Content-Type` to `text/xml`.

Here is what I am seeing on the other end, from within my Rails application:

```
request.env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = "text/xml"
request.content_type = "application/xml"
```

`request.content_type` is actually `action_dispatch.request.content_type`

1. What is the difference between `request.env['CONTENT_TYPE']` and `request.content_type`?
2. Why are these two values different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`request.env` contains Rack's "thoughts" on what the content type is. Generally, this is the content type of the request that you have made.

`request.content_type` on the other hand is Rails's interpretation of what it thinks the content type is, based off the format of the request. These are defined in a file called `mime_types.rb` in Rails (I can't recall which part, but with that you should be able to locate it), and additional ones can be specified in `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`.

Comment: Thanks! Great explanation. So am I correct in saying that `request.content_type` is more of a safety/convenience mechanism for those lazy people who fail to set the `Content-Type` on the request header? In other words, if I am **expecting** a **certain** `Content-Type`, I should be checking `request.env['CONTENT_TYPE']` and **not** `request.content_type` as Rails will do guess-work to figure out this value based on the actual content.